# Message Passing from Polygon To Bnb With Axelar

Tags: blockchain, solidity, axelar

I am facing an issue while executing a call from polygon to bnb on remix. Followed the example from documentation of Hello World message passing but it reverts every time.

[image: axelar hello world code 1]

[image: axelar hello world code 2]

This is the error I am receiving

```
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"execution reverted","id":7635389025522819}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was forgetting to pass a gas value when I was trying to execute the `sendMessage` function. Passing in 1e18 wei and making sure metamask was on correct network fixed the problem.